# Catching exceptions of multiple types

Tags: postgresql, haskell, exception

When I query [my database](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html), it might throw [one of four different kinds of exceptions](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.1/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#v:query).

```
FormatError
QueryError
ResultError
SqlError
```

I want to write a function that catches any of those 4 exceptions generated by `query` and lifts them into `ExceptT`.

```
runQuery :: (ToRow q, FromRow r) => Query -> q -> ExceptT ServantErr IO [r]
runQuery conn q sub = do
    res <- liftIO $ try $ Postgres.query conn q sub
    case res of
      Left err -> throwError (postgresErr err)
      Right r -> return r

postgresErr :: ??? -> ServantErr
postgresErr e = err500 { errBody = ByteString.pack (show e) }
```

This doesn't work. `try` isn't catching anything. How can I catch any of the 4 exception types, and map it to a `ServantErr` depending on the type, but still allow any exceptions I don't handle to pass through?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

GHC's [`Exception` class forms a hierarchy](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Control-Exception.html), with the `SomeException` type at the top. So to catch any exception whatsoever, use that:

```
postgresErr :: SomeException -> ServantErr
```

(Ideally `postgresql-simple` could have added its own intermediate catch-all exception type that you could use, but I couldn't see any.)

If you want to catch *exactly* those four, the best way I know is to use the [`catches`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/Control-Exception.html#v:catches) function:

```
catches :: IO a -> [Handler a] -> IO a
```

Unfortunately this requires you to provide one `Handler` for each of them (although probably they'll only differ in their type signature).

Comment: What if I only want to catch them if they are one of those 4 types?

Comment: @SeanClarkHess Added some about that.